# Python - Get users Outlook to email me

Tags: python, email, outlook

not sure if this is possible.

I built a program in Python for people at work, and I want to see who is using it and when.

Essentially, if they run the program I want it to (if open) send me an email from their Outlook account with a certain title and body (even better if it can delete that sent email but it isnt essential).

Is this possible in Python and if so, what should I be looking at?

Many thanks

Edit: This isn't malicious, I will be telling people that they will be emailing me.

Comment: You want your program to secretly send emails from your user's email account and delete the records of them? That sounds pretty sinister.

Comment: Haha! I would tell people... it is crazy what malicious stuff I could do in my organisation but I am a nice guy and I like my job :)

Comment: Don't forget to make it clear that something is being sent. Be transparent or no one will want to use your script ever again!

Comment: Yes, I totally agree. I updated my content to make this more clear. I just dont want to fill peoples email box up with emails (as they might have a certain system).... either way, the accepted solution gets around this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclamer: it's not ok to secretly send any data from user's workstation to you. User should be informed that the script will send some data back to you.

*Is it possible in Python to send an email from a certain address?*

Yes.

Explanation:
You just need an access to an SMPT server. Field 'from' can be any email address. Here is an example function sending HTML formatted mail.

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
import smtplib


def spam(sender, user, msg):
    """
    Sends mail from sender to user. msg is mail content in html code
    """

    server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.your.server.com")
    mail = MIMEMultipart()
    mail["Subject"] = "Your subject"
    mail["From"] = sender
    mail["To"] = user
    msg_str = MIMEText("<html><body>" + msg + "</body></html>", 'html')
    mail.attach(msg_str)

    server.sendmail(sender, user, mail.as_string())
    server.quit()
    print("Mail sent")
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much! Thats even better than what I was thinking as they wont know they are emailing me as technically they are not. Really appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1):

this solution would not use outlook, so it may fall out of scope of the subject

why don't you create a log file in a shared folder on the user's workstation

have the python script update the log file with pertinent info, relating to the usage and health of the program that you wish to monitor

then retrieve the log file at some interval

log files are a normal thing for a lot of programs

and there would be no covert emails involved

Comment: Thank you, I am looking into this now. I managed to get the email thing working with a gmail account but it turns out my employers firewall stops me doing this :)